# javascript Match, get numbers

Tags: javascript

I started my self-study javascript 10 days ago and I have to do one exercise. I 've read related articles through several sources also incl javascript manual. I don't have too much programming knowledge, so what I did is somehow not so good. Anyway I write here because I hope that somebody could explain me , how should it be done. So tks in advance. The exercise is :

Complete the below javascript: Find and print all the numbers in the sentence in one table. If there are no numbers in the sentence, print "No numbers!". Try checking the sentence for numbers using the test () method:

```
var sentence = "J07ku7 k1rj01774v47 54n0j4 num3r0174 käy77ä3n.";

function print numbers () {
  ### put your code here ###    
}
```

**Example output**

```
0,7,7,1,0,1,7,7,4,4,7,5,4,0,4,3,0,1,7,4,7,7,3
```

Comment: _"...using the test () method"_ - Which `test()` method are they talking about?

Comment: And what have you already tried to solve this on your own?

Comment: `function print numbers` you can't have a function name like that

Comment: `sentence.match(/\d/g)?.join() || "No numbers"`

Comment: "string" @andreas

Comment: oh I just figured out that `the test method` is referring to the regex test method ... what a waste of code when it can be done with one single line

Comment: check out my answer using `match()`, only one line of code

Answer (score 1):

One line answer aka the easiest way:

```js
var sentence = "J07ku7 k1rj01774v47 54n0j4 num3r0174 käy77ä3n.";
console.log((new RegExp("[0-9]")).test(sentence) ? sentence.match(/[0-9]{1}/g).join() : 'no numbers!');
```

```js
var sentence = "bfdbfrgthjtjhgdbdsfytjyukrger";
console.log((new RegExp("[0-9]")).test(sentence) ? sentence.match(/[0-9]{1}/g).join() : 'no numbers!');
```

Edited so it would use test and write "no numbers" if no numbers are given.

Generally if you are not familiar with `?:` syntax, it means exactly the same as:

```
if((new RegExp("[0-9]")).test(sentence)){ // this returns true if found, false when not
   console.log(sentence.match(/[0-9]{1}/g).join());
}else{
   console.log('no numbers!');
}
```

Comment: tks I get first test right but the second test is uncorrect Example output; 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,0

Comment: @kami ok I get it, used test and returns no numbers if there are no numbers

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to chunk the sentences into arrays of character, you can use `"the sentences".split("")`
2. Loop through array check each character if is numeric or not using parseFloat

```js
var sentence = "J07ku7 k1rj01774v47 54n0j4 num3r0174 käy77ä3n.";
sentence.split("").forEach(myChar=>
!isNaN(parseFloat(myChar))&&console.log(myChar)
);
```

Comment: Sorry but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64313434/javascript-match-get-numbers#64313537 is cleaner approach..

Comment: tks for your answer, but i should get now for right anwser : "0,1,1,8,9,9,9,8,8,1,9,9,9,1,1,9,7,2,5,3"

Comment: @MoshFeu I don't agree, but the problem in this answer is that when it's `0`, the `pareFloat()` will return `0`, that will be interpreted as `false`

Comment: That is true. You should use parse int with an octet. Parsing js arrays of string to numbers can have an unexpected behavior if you don't understand its mechanics.

Comment: yeah i just added isNaN

Comment: @AdamMudianto yeah better

Comment: never heard of `in_numeric ` in my entire 6years+ js codes

Answer (score 0):

This is how you implement a function like that in order to achive correct result. There are some pitfalls that you might encounter in such simple code.

```
var sentence = "J07ku7 k1rj01774v47 54n0j4 num3r0174 käy77ä3n.";

function printNumbers(text) {
  return text
    .replace(/\s/g, "")
    .split('')
    .filter(str => !isNaN(str))
    .map(octet => parseInt(octet, 10))
}

console.log(printNumbers(sentence))
```

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/dq8p0r3o/

Comment: the title of the question does suggest to use match :p

Answer (score 0):

You can solve do it in several ways. The short ES6 way is-

```js
const getNumbers = str => str.split('').filter(ch => !isNaN(ch)).map(x => x >> 0).join();

const sentance = "J07ku7 k1rj01774v47 54n0j4 num3r0174 käy77ä3n.";
const res = getNumbers(sentance);

console.log(res.length > 0 ? res : 'No Numbers!');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Comment: your output is an array ... example output suggests a string (no `[]` in example output)

Answer (score 0):

sorry but the task need the two output;

```
var sentence = "J07ku7 k1rj01774v47 54n0j4 num3r0174 käy77ä3n.";

function print numbers () {
  /* put your code here */
}
```

**Example output**

first output:

> 0,1,1,8,9,9,9,8,8,1,9,9,9,1,1,9,7,2,5,3

second output:

> 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,0.

i get first one right but second one i have hitch with,